# How to customize GDM Login Screen on Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty ubuntu-gnome

Tags: gnome, 17.04, login-screen, gdm

How can I customize gdm Login Screen on Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty  **ubuntu-gnome**? Just background and maybe gtk themes.

I have tried many things and none seems to work.

Like this guide https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/desktop-shield.html.en

Also I have tried to edit:
/usr/share/gdm/greeter.dconf-defaults && dconf update
and similar solutions.

I didn't find any graphic tool that works. Many docs on Internet only talks about really old ubuntu versions, gdm2 etc.

Just to be clear, Im using UBUNTU-GNOME version - 17.04 Zesty

Thanks

Comment: Open Settings, click on Background, click on Lock Screen.

Comment: ups, my mistake. not lock screen but login screen. Login screen will show up after you move the lok screen up. You can change the lock screen pretty easily like you said. The Login Window has more options, like show up user card, accessibility options, etc. Right now, its just a ugly black screen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The login screen is now managed by ligthdm.

sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter
sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings

Run lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings to confgure

Comment: I'm not using Linux/Ubuntu anymore so I can't test anymore. But your answer makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: I told gnome to use gdm